# adding new pandas series and setting to false

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I am adding the following code:

```
 r = df_1[~df_1isin(
        df_2.to_dict('list')).all(1)] 
 r['is_sent'] = pd.Series(False).bool()
```

The purpose is to narrow down a search between two dataframes, I then want to add a new column(pd.series) and set those findings to false. This does what I intended to do but a message is returned:

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Can anyone explain what this references and give an example of what is the correct way to approuch this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is that slicing a DataFrame creates a `weakref` between the slice and the original DataFrame. This then triggers the warning on the next line when you do an assignment.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,1,1,2])
r = df[df.isin([1]).all(1)]

r['new_col'] = False
#<ipython-input-210-d5f9bda478c4>:9: SettingWithCopyWarning:  ...
```

---

You can verify there's a weakref using a built in method `._is_copy`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,1,1,2])
r = df[df.isin([1]).all(1)]
r._is_copy
#<weakref at 0x142b10e00; to 'DataFrame' at 0x14361ed00>
```

And the easiest way to break this is to use `.copy()` to force a deep copy so that `r` has no relationship to `df`, which will get rid of the warning.

```
r = df[df.isin([1]).all(1)].copy()
r._is_copy
#None

r['new_col'] = False
# No warning!
```

---

Finally, this warning often *seems* to be hit or miss, but this is because many pandas operations **return a new object** and so if there are operations between the slicing and assignment it's likely that those operations themselves break the weakref, which then prevents the warning. For instance, a simple operation like multiplying by 2 would create a new object and you get no warning.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,1,1,2])

r = df[df.isin([1]).all(1)]
print(r._is_copy)
#<weakref at 0x13e6ad0e0; to 'DataFrame' at 0x1436227c0>

r = r*2   # Breaks the reference
print(r._is_copy)
# None

r['new_col'] = False
# No warning!
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate the thorough answer here. This makes sense!